# how to call receivePort.listen() at multiple widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using below code to register send port then I want to listen it on multiple place is it possible any how?
I made receivePort global accessible.

```
IsolateNameServer.registerPortWithName(receivePort.sendPort, "downloadingVideos");

receivePort.listen(downloadListener) - on widget1
receivePort.listen(downloadListener) - on widget2
receivePort.listen(downloadListener) - on widget3
```

Comment: I have used Provider for updating state on multiple widgets for now.